# Concourse: `fly hijack` returns "error: open /dev/stdin: permission denied"

Tags: shell, docker, concourse

I am trying to hijack a Concourse task container by using the following command:

```
$ fly  -t caas hijack --job=deploymen/deploy-jenkins
1: build #8, step: deploy-jenkins-with-helm, type: task
2: build #8, step: k8s-pipelines-repo, type: get
choose a container: 1
```

After selecting the container, `fly` returns with the following error message and I can't hijack the container:

```
error: open /dev/stdin: permission denied
```

I am running the command with a non-root user on a RHEL machine. Any ideas?

Comment: Sometimes it depend on the docker container you're using (you can edit your question with such detail). Also always make sure the container has a shell available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had the same issue and struggled quite a bit to find out the root cause. For me it was actually that I was logging into a remote system and changing my user context with `sudo su <username>` . This effectively causes issues with /dev/stdin, /dev/stdout, ... which is very well explained in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38538/bash-dev-stderr-permission-denied .

I was able to work around this issue by using `sudo login <username>` instead. Hope that helps.

Yours Joda :)

Answer (score -1):

Could you try running that command as sudo?

```
$ sudo fly -t caas hijack --job=deploymen/deploy-jenkins
```